# Adding graphs to PDFKIT using Chartjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts, pdfkit

I'm running a NodeJS application (MongoDB, Express, Vue) and I need to export some data to pdf using [PDFKIT](https://pdfkit.org/docs/guide.pdf), this data is also being displayed in html by a vue file.

I was trying to add a graph to the pdf in several ways, but I couldn't. My main focus was on creatign an image so I could pass it to PDFKIT.

My problem with ChartJS is that you have to provide a ctx element to it, but my code is runing from a js file on the backend, I have no html element to give it, nor do I want this chart to be displayed (only to create an image for it, so I could pass the image to PDFKIT).

I also tried using html2canvas from my vue file, but it didnt work.

I would appreciate any idea on fixing my problem with ChartJS or maybe another method.

Comment: you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas , i used this to insert dynamic char in pdfkit

Comment: Another solution easy to implement Quickchart https://quickchart.io/
This is based on ChartJS and you don't need to implement node-canvas etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google charts. By converting it into the image and render into pdf.

```
const GoogleChartsNode = require('google-charts-node');

// Define your chart drawing function
function drawChart() {
  const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population',],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000]
  ]);

  const options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    }
  };

  const chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Render the chart to image
const image = await GoogleChartsNode.render(drawChart);
```

For more information refer : [Server-side image rendering for Google Charts by quickchart.io](https://quickchart.io/documentation/google-charts-image-server/#example)

Comment: Add the variable into your doc.image(image) method